# how can i copy a html table from a website and paste it into outlook and keep the table formatting

Tags: microsoft-outlook, website, html, copy-paste

i have an html table on a website, but when i copy and paste into outlook, it shoves all the data together.  I have tried with HTML mode, Rich text mode, etc but still can't seem to have it show up with the table structure in my outlook email.

any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest making an HTML email. You can grab the code for the table easily using [Firefox](http://getfirefox.com) and the [Firebug add-on](http://getfirebug.com/).

With both Firefox and Firebug up and running, navigate to the page containing the table, click Firebug's element inspector, then click on the table. You will be brought to the table's code in Firebug where you can easily right-click to copy it's HTML code for use in the HTML email:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There is a better solution available now in Firefox.

Download the plugin called [Dafizilla Table2Clipboard](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/dafizilla-table2clipboard/contribute/roadblock/?src=userprofile&version=1.5.3.1) and install as firefox addon. Now you will have an additional option in the right click when you click inside a table.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, Outlook Express is way better than the full Outlook when it comes to writing html emails. Maybe you ought to give it a try if this is a life or death matter...

Comment: life or death ?? no . .not that important